# How to redirect output as input in command line?

Tags: c#, redirect, command-line

I want to write a console application which can handle input in command line as below:

```
type file1.csv file2.csv | TestPipe.exe input1
```

or
   `((type file1.csv file2.csv | TestPipe +) & (type file3.csv file4.csv | TestPipe +)) | TestPipe +`

In my TestPipe code, I just receive input1 as print input1 as below:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Your input is {0}", args[0]));
    }
```

Now I want to run TestPipe in another ConsoleApplication.exe which has the code as below:

```
        Process Test = new Process();
        Test.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\TestPipe\TestPipe\bin\Debug\TestPipe.exe";
        Test.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        Test.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        Test.Start();
        StreamWriter myStreamWriter = Test.StandardInput;
        string inputTxt;
        do
        {
            inputTxt = Console.ReadLine();
        } while (inputTxt.Length != 0);

        myStreamWriter.Close();
        Test.WaitForExit();
        Test.Close();
```

However, I got unhandled exception at `} while (inputTxt.Length != 0);`

Question:

1) How to change the code so I could run `type file1.csv file2.csv | TestPipe.exe input1` in command line?

2) How to get the file1.csv, file2.csv string value in TestPipe?

3) I want to run nested redirect input like this: `((type file1.csv file2.csv | TestPipe +) & (type file3.csv file4.csv | TestPipe +)) | TestPipe +`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start Your application with following command

```
var proc = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("D://TestPipe.exe", "type file1.csv file2.csv | TestPipe.exe input1");
```

and you can access those values in TestPipe.exe using args[] in Main

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       //args[0] == type 
       //args[1] == file1.csv
       //args[1] == file2.csv
    }
```

Comment: how to get file1.csv, file2.csv in TestPipe.exe?

Comment: Hope Edited answer will help you.!

Comment: Is the Main sub-routine with string[] args located in TestPipe.exe or in another ConsoleApplication.exe?

Comment: in TestPipe.exe